# Initialize Struct Array with Null C++

Tags: c++, hash, struct

I'm trying to implement separate chaining using array of linked list. First I initialized struct array, which eventually consists of 10 head nodes and initially nothing, not 0, nothing is in the node.

I thought this would work:

```
void Hash::sepChain(int key){
    int i;

    //initialize array with Null
    myNode a[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        a[i] = NULL;
    }

    myNode->item = key;
    myNode->next = a[key%tableSize];
    a[key%tableSize] = myNode;

}
```

but I am getting this error.

```
hash.cpp:176:10: error: no viable overloaded '='
a[i] = NULL;
~~~~ ^ ~~~~
./hash.hpp:30:8: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator)
  not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'const myNode' for 1st
  argument
struct myNode{
   ^
```

this is how I wrote struct in .hpp

```
struct myNode{
    int item;// the value that goes into the node
    myNode *next;
};
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you missed a `*`.  `myNode a[10];` should be `myNode* a[10];` by the looks of it.

Comment: I don't understand why almost every beginner here are trying to implement a linked list. First, `std::list` exists, and second, linked list are not so great unless you have a *very* large amount of data and you have to make insertion in arbitrary places.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It is a typical homework problem for new CS students.  You have to be able to make your own container before they let you use the standard container.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot some people do it because they have assignments to do, or they just at least once want to implement their own linked list data structure.

Comment: Yea it was assigned by my instructor. @NathanOliver Thanks. That fixed the error. I'm also getting error for doing myNode->item=key;, I wrote this to put int key as the value that my node holds. The error says, cannot use arrow operator on a type. Could you help me understand why?

Comment: You can't even use `nullptr`? Has NathanOlivier said, you can't init raw data type with `NULL` (at least you shouldn't): `NULL` is not a `myNode` type (same for `nullptr`). If you want use `NULL` or `nullptr`, use a pointer type instead.

Comment: @Philipp With the advent of the Internet,  you can easily find a working linked list, understand how it works, and then see what the code is that is wrong in the student's implementation.  It is much easier today then it was decades ago, where you maybe had one and if you could afford it, two textbooks to figure out how to write a linked list.  My point being that there *is* an inordinate amount of linked list questions posted, and it's hard to fathom why more research isn't done by the student before asking.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right of course and I'm not arguing that there are not better ways to get help/solve the problem. But it's a reason why they want to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[i] = NULL;
```

is not right since the LHS of that operation is an object of type `myNode`. It's not a pointer to `myNode`.

You could use:

```
a[i] = myNode{};
```

You could also use:

```
myNode a[10] = {};
```

and get rid of the `for` loop.

Comment: That gives me error saying "error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction"

Comment: You need C++11 for the `{}` syntax, aka `-std=c++11` for g++ and clang. If you can't use C++11, initialize myNode with `myNode()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set to NULL variable that do not refer to pointers. If you want to inizialize a's element to NULL you have to declare it as

```
    myNode *a[10]
```

Comment: That won't compile. Please revise how array of pointer syntax works.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  It was my distraction